# Travis build fail with error 65

Tags: xcode, travis-ci

I have a Travis CI setup on GitHub. I use it to check my commits for iOS app. The problem is, I very often and randomly get an error 65. I have yet to find a solution.

**When I restart the job 2-3 times after it has failed it passes in 90% of times.**

I previously also had a problem with logs being too verbose for Travis (>4MB) but I added `xcpretty` to fix that.

Errors I took from log:

```
...
Generating 'XYZ.app.dSYM'
❌  error: couldn't remove '/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XYZ-aaltcjvmshpmlufpmzdsgbernspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XYZ.app/SomeName.storyboardc' after command failed: Directory not empty
...
```

And then at the end of Travis log:

```
Testing failed:
    The file “056-Jj-FAu-view-XmS-Ro-0cO.nib” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
    error: couldn't remove '/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XYZ-aaltcjvmshpmlufpmzdsgbernspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XYZ.app/SomeName.storyboardc' after command failed: Directory not empty
    error: lipo: can't move temporary file: /Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XYZ-aaltcjvmshpmlufpmzdsgbernspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XYZ.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/XYZ to file: /Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XYZ-aaltcjvmshpmlufpmzdsgbernspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XYZ.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/XYZ.lipo (No such file or directory)
    Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
** TEST FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    LinkStoryboards
    LinkStoryboards
(2 failures)
The command "./scripts/build.sh" exited with 65.
```

I am using `Xcode 8` both in Xcode and Travis settings.

Comment: That's a problem appearing on different CI's. With all different kind of trys across the web https://discuss.circleci.com/t/xcode-exit-code-65-ui-tests/7201/13. It seems like somehow starting the simulator before the build command with launching instruments was a hack prior to Xcode8. That supposedly doesn't work anymore. I haven't looked into different options yet.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, good question. Occasionally, `xcodebuild` steps that are failing during the codesigning step can be addressed using `travis_retry` - Travis will retry the step 3 times for any non-zero exit status, which should reduce the need for you to restart it manually. There are some suggested code snippets in the [`travis-ci/travis-ci` GitHub issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6675#issuecomment-257964767) on this as well. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I'm following that thread and am active in it as well, as you may have seen:) Unfortunately, pre-warming simulator does not change anything for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running into the error code 65 (from random failures) here's a command you can pipe on the end of your `xcodebuild` (assuming you're running tests) command to get back more consistent results:

`(XCODEBUILD_COMMAND_HERE) | awk 'BEGIN {success=0} $0 ~ /.* tests, with 0 failures \(.*/ {success=1} {print $0} END {if(success==0){exit 1}}`

This looks for `tests, with 0 failures (` in your output text, thus using the text output of `xcodebuild` instead of the status code of `xcodebuild` to determine success.

Note: Keep in mind, if you do something like `NSLog(' tests, with 0 failures (');` in your code you make get a false positive, it's very unlikely to happen by accident. You may have to update `tests, with 0 failures (` in the awk script between updates of `xcodebuild`. But, having consistent results with `xcodebuild` is definitely worth that price.